# How to access Vuex store in Vue setup() method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

How do I access the [Vuex](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/) store in Vue when using the `setup()` method?

I don't have access to the regular `this.$store` variable anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the composition API [documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html) you have to use the following syntax:

```
import { computed } from 'vue' // If not already imported
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()

    return {
      // access a state in computed function
      count: computed(() => store.state.count),

      // access a getter in computed function
      double: computed(() => store.getters.double)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to do it in vue 2.7 (with composition API)?

Comment: @Md.A.Apu This should do the trick
`
<script setup>
... import store and other deps
const store = useStore();
const count = computed(() => store.state.count);
etc...
</script>
`

Comment: Note that you may need to add __import { computed } from 'vue'__ just below the import of { useStore }, otherwise it throws an error on the use of the computed keyword.